# Where to store credential in terraform-gcp-github project?

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, terraform

I have a terraform project that accesses a google cloud bucket.  All pull requests are done through github.  However, I'm not sure where I'm supposed to securely store my bucket credentials?  Of course I don't want to upload them to github but I'm not sure where they should be kept.  This is my variables file

```
variable "credentials_filepath" {
  default = "../../../creds.json"
}
```

And this is my main file

```
provider "google" {

  credentials = file(var.credentials_filepath)

  project = var.project
  region  = "europe-west2"
  zone    = "europe-west2-a"
}
```

Comment: Where are you running your terraform?

Comment: Would you mind to run your terraform from the Cloud Build? In that case you may be able to grant permissions on the bucket to a cloud build service account in advance, so the credentials won’t be needed.

Answer (score 2):

The main idea is to store the secrets securely in a secrets manager and to use a wrapper that makes the secrets available as environment variables only for the duration of the wrapper process.

Among the tools that I can recommend: [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/), [gopass](https://github.com/gopasspw/gopass), [summon](https://github.com/cyberark/summon).

For example, once the secrets are stored in GPG and you have the gpg-agent configured, you can run:

```
TF_VAR_secret=$(pass gc/myproject) terraform ...
```

- This will tell the shell to set the environment variable `TF_VAR_secret` to the output of `pass gc/myproject`.
- That command tells `pass` to use gpg and gpg-agent to read the value of the secret stored at `gc/myproject`.
- `secret` is a Terraform variable and `TF_VAR_secret` tells Terraform to fill that variable from that environment variable. (See Terraform [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/variables.html#environment-variables)).